# php - Facebook Login works in localhost but getting error in server side

Tags: php, facebook-login

Checked all the files name and other required information (such as credentials) and all are spelled correctly. i have also created a separate app for localhost and server testing. Here is the error i am getting when user tried to login with facebook on live server **failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in facebook login**

Comment: There are few hosting providers which specifically block facebook API...

Comment: check if your hosting does this?

Comment: @DevanshuGoyal how to check if my hosting provider has blocked facebook api?